# C++ Склеить макрос

Tags: c++, макросы

Пытаюсь склеить такой макрос:

```
#define fileNameCut ((std::string(__FILE__).erase(0, std::string(__FILE__).rfind("\\") + 1)).c_str())
#define msg_s ("Error\nin file: " fileNameCut )
#define msg_b (fileNameCut)
```

Вызов:

```
int main(){
//msg_b//Замечательно работает и обрезает путь до файла как нужно!
printf("%s", msg_s);
return 0;
}
```

Вывод компилятора:

```
Ошибка  C2059   синтаксическая ошибка: строка   v 1.0   source.cpр  
Ошибка  C2064   результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 1 аргументов
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

При разворачивании макроса получится

```
"Error\nin file: " ((std::string(__FILE__).erase(...)).c_str())
```

Во-первых, `erase` возвращает итератор, а не строку, по этому там нельзя вызвать `c_str`.
Bo-вторых, `"..." str.c_str()` - это не валидный код. Можно склеить два литерала (`"a" "b"`), но не литерал и строку.

Также `std::string(__FILE__).rfind("\\")` - это платформо-зависимый код, слеши могут быть любыми.

Comment: erase возвращает строку и там можно вызвать c_str(), но не в этом дело,  как решить проблему, ?